# Loading a different component.html file from a component.ts file?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, routes

I'm new to angular and I was wondering how I could load a different `home.component.html` file from a method that's inside `books.component.ts`.

This is my `books.component.ts` file.

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import {BooksService} from '../books.service';
 import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
 import { Router } from '@angular/router';


 @Component({
  selector: 'app-books',
  templateUrl: './books.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./books.component.css']
 })
export class BooksComponent {

  constructor(private httpService: BooksService, private router:Router) {

  }

  status : any;

  onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    console.log("AM I HERE AT LEAST");


    this.httpService.checkLoginCred(f.value).subscribe(

     data => {

    // console.log(Object.values(data)[0]);
    this.status = Object.values(data)[0];

    if(this.status === "Successful"){

       var path = "../home/home.component.html";
     // console.log($location.path());
      //console.log(this.router);
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      console.log("GREAT!");
    }

    return true;
  }

  );


  }


}
```

my `app.module.ts` looks like so:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BooksComponent } from './books/books.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
 declarations: [
   AppComponent,
BooksComponent,
HomeComponent,
 ],
 imports: [
   RouterModule.forRoot([
     {
       path: 'home',
       component:  HomeComponent
     }
   ]),
   BrowserModule,
   HttpClientModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
   FormsModule,
   ReactiveFormsModule

 ],
 providers: [],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my `books.component.ts` and `books.component.html` files are in my `books` directory.

my `home.component.ts` and `home.component.html` files are in my `home` directory

I've attached a screenshot of how my directory structure looks like.

So far I'm trying to use `this.router.navigate` but I'm not having much luck with that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

**EDIT**

My `home.component.ts` file looks like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent {

  constructor() { }

  }
```

Comment: Add your home.component.ts ?  I think like book.component.ts you can add your home component html directly in your home.component.ts at `templateUrls` on your `@Component({})` decorator

Comment: Do you mean to put home.component.html in the templateUrls of home.component.ts?

Comment: Yep that will render the component html when you use route.navigate

Comment: But I already have this `@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})`  in my `home.component.ts` , yet it still doesn't render the `home.component.html` file

Comment: Okay then - initally which component gets loaded ? Book ?

Comment: yeah! I added how my `home.component.ts` file looks like. But initially, it is `book.component.html` that gets loaded.

Additionally, in  my url, it does show /home. However it somehow doesn't render the actually `home.component.html` file. Instead it still stays at `books.component.html`

Comment: Then in your app.component.html you have binded `<app-book></app-book>` - I'm i right -  that makes your book component to render - problem is its not rendering from route and thus angular doesn't know where to bind the home component since there is no `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` -

Comment: My `app.component.html` file actually looks like this `<app-books></app-books>

<app-home></app-home>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>` does the order matter? p.s (I also edited my previous comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed - here is the solution - hope it works

Add only `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` on `app.compoment.html` and using routing try to render the components

Your route should read as

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
     {
       path: 'home',
       component:  HomeComponent
     },
     {
       path: 'book',
       component:  BookComponent
     },
     {
       path: '',
       redirectTo:  'book'
       pathMatch: 'full'
     }
   ])
```

Thus on the initial load your path will match empty and redirect to `BookComponent` and inside the book component when you navigate it will load the `HomeComponent` inside the `AppComponent` html

Hope this might solve your problem - happy coding :-)